# Rails: How do I install this JavaScript correctly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I tried get typist.js to work but I'm having a difficult time as it doesn't seem to do anything. Here are the steps I took to get it to work.

https://github.com/positionly/Typist

`typist.js` in the `javascript folder`

Put this code in the **views/users/show.html.erb**

```
JavaScript is <strong id="typist-element" data-typist="ugly,not as good an CoffeeScript">great</strong>
```

css file in **applications.css**

```
.selectedText {
  background: #f00;
}
```

but nothing happens, it doesn't do anything. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include it in `application.js`?, add this line to your application.js file

```
//= require typist
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. Nothing, it doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately. I just wasn't sure what to do with the .coffee file